# How to register singleton qml type with std function for a callback in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, types, qml

Is there a way to register a singleton qml type using custom std function for a callback? If there is not, are there particular reasons for not allowing it?
In Qt docmentation I could only find  qmlRegisterSingletonType which take function pointer.

Thanks

Comment: @Jesper So you are advising him not to use cin, cout cerr and clog?

Comment: @Jesper according to my understanding Singleton qml type registration only means that the same instance registered under particular name will be used across all qmls, but this doesn't resrict me from creating multiple instances of same C++ class as long as they are registered under different names, am I right?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth so you are saying that globals are a great idea?

Comment: @Jesper Sometimes they are a sensible solution to particular problem. Nothing is a "great idea" all the time.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm not sure cin and cout are Singletons in a sense Jesper implied. Moreover cin and cout are instances of istream and ostream classes which are not singletons themselves in GOF sense.  To his defense I might say I  would prefer not to use singletons either, but again this is not relevant to my question as I have oultined in previous comment.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - sure, we can agree that *every tool* in the toolbox has a use. But, certain tools - like globals/singletons just have a *very* low usefulness IMHO.

Comment: @Dima  No, they are global variables (or at least global in the std namespace). I realise this is not particularly releveant to your question, which is why I commented rather than answered. And also because I don't know the answer.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I would prefer to distinguish globals and singletons, but AGAIN THIS IS NOT RELEVANT TO MY QUESTION

Comment: @JesperJuhl you can't tell someone to stop using singletons when the API of the toolkit they're using requires it - it's even in the name. This is a perfectly acceptable practice in QML; almost every project with styling uses some form of singleton. Your opinion isn't relevant here, especially when it doesn't help answer OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is not, are there particular reasons for not allowing it?

Because it affects Qt's binary compatibility promise. [This thread](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2017-March/029003.html) on the development mailing list explains it:

> > Hi,
> >
> > I understand that there are limitations (to put it mildly) regarding the use
> >     of API from the C++ standard library in Qt API itself due to the inability
> >     to extend our binary compatibility promise. I'm curious though whether
> >     std::function falls under the same umbrella?
>
> Yes, it does: the binary representation (including size), or the
>   mangling is  not guaranteed to be the same across stdlib
>   implementations.
>
> So here are the choice:
>
> 1- Re-implement QFunction, with similar semantic as std::function.
>
> 2- Lift the constraint that we can't use the stdlib in our ABI
>
> 3- Do nothing and keep using awkward interface when we need callback.
>
> #3 is, as usual, the easier (status quo) and will probably happen. #1 is a  somewhat difficult task, but not that hard. We will just end up
>   with a poor  copy of std::function. #2 was always dismissed in the
>   past, but I think it  should be seriously considered.
>
> (The same applies to std::unique_ptr, too)
>
> > I understand that we permit the use of std::function in Windows specific API
> >     of QProcess, which may or may not be different. However I'm curious about
> >     this in the context of API that is intended to be fully cross-platform.
>
> Actually, this is breaking the policy. Even on Windows, there are
>   different  std lib implementations.